# Unable to get session for socket in sailsjs after restart

Tags: javascript, socket.io, sails.js

I trying to build socket driven application on sailsjs, it is small and I need only memory session adapter, but when I restart application, I getting after `socket.get('/')`:

```
Could not parse: No session data returned, and an error was encountered saving session data for the first time: undefined SyntaxError {stack: (...), message: "Unexpected token N"} sails.io.js:142

Uncaught Error: Server response could not be parsed!
No session data returned, and an error was encountered saving session data for the first time: undefined
```

I understand that my session is lost, but can't find any way to restore it, or even take care of this error.

Is there any way to request new session cookie for socket without reloading the page ?

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: @JustDon't I already did: `socket.get('/');`.  On sailsjs just `sails new testapp;cd testapp;sails lift;` - open `http://localhost:1337` in browser, kill app (`^C`) run `sails lift` and try to run `socket.get('/')` from browser console.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem here is that by default Sails uses `MemoryStore` to handle sessions, which means whenever you lower Sails (or whenever the application crashes, even if it is being restarted with `forever`, etc.) all the sessions will just be automatically gone.

The solution is as simple as changing the session handling to an external adapter. In `config/session.js` generated by default you already have two examples of setup for such an adapter, namely, for Redis and MongoDB, so all you have to do is to uncomment corresponding lines (and don't forget a comma after `secret` value). For example, if you go with mongo, it'll be something like

```
module.exports.session = {
  secret: 'c827f7e0dc520d83d63b5c9c055b1d00', // !!

  // Redis setup example is here...    

  // Uncomment the following lines to use your Mongo adapter as a session store
  adapter: 'mongo',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 27017,
  db: 'sails',
  collection: 'sessions'

  // Optional Values:
  //
  // # Note: url will override other connection settings
  // url: 'mongodb://user:pass@host:port/database/collection',
  //
  // username: '',
  // password: '',
  // auto_reconnect: false,
  // ssl: false,
  // stringify: true    
};
```

Of course, in this case you should have `mongod` running on your machine.

**UPDATE**

Ok, if there is a MemoryStore limitation which can't be avoided (that was the original question), then reinitializing the socket session without reloading the page becomes a bit tricky, but still possible. In order to do it one should:

1. Make an AJAX (or JSONP in case of CORS) request to your server to get the new session ID. For example, it can be as simple as having a controller returning a JSON with the session ID, let's say `api/controllers/TestController.js`:

   `module.exports = {
     index: function(req, res) {
         res.send(req.sessionID);
     }
   };`

So, once you detected that the session is lost, use `$.get('/test')` to get the new session ID.

1. Then pass the new session ID as a `cookie` parameter while reconnecting the socket:

   `socket.socket.connect('/?cookie=<newSessionID>')`
2. `socket.get("/", function (response) { console.log(response); })` will work after that.

It's kind of a quick hack, and there's probably a more elegant way to wrap it (e.g. send session ID in headers, not in the body, etc.), but the idea is simple: make an AJAX-request to get a new session and pass its ID as `cookie` parameter to reconnect the socket.

Comment: **it is small and I need only memory session adapter**


the question was "how to request new session cookie for socket without reloading the page ?" I mean I understand that the problem is because session lost. But is there any way to get session again ? now I solving it using `window.location.reload()` on parse error. Also if saved session lost by any reason I will get same problem.

Comment: @eicto My bad, sorry, didn't pay enough attention to the initial question. I'm looking into it now, though. This one is really catchy. The advice I have found so far says "... send a JSONP request first from the client to the Sails.js server to get the cookie (be sure it's the same domain!!)" Haven't try this one yet, but I will let your know if something works out. Thanks!

Comment: btw, do you think that it is enough to make sailsjs bugreport like "non json reply in case of session error" ?

Comment: @eicto well, it doesn't seem exactly like a bug to me, 'cause it wasn't announced to be supposed to work this way. it may be like a feature.

Comment: hm, but it cause client application crash.  (imaginate that it is not an web application, but some just api client, which sure that if there is no connection error but json message) and it getting unparsable "random" string.

Comment: @eicto Ok, I spent some time on this one and managed it to work for me. See the update on the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and reading [this issue](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/1026#issuecomment-32992175) i realised that a new session will be created just after an http request to sails. I have the front end served separately on static files, thus i use just socket.io towards sails, and this is the reason why the session is not renewed.

With either a persistent or volatile session adapter, when a session is expired it should be renewed.

So, without the need to switch to a persistent adapter, i just added an empty file under the sails assets folder, like in `assets/js/renew-session.js` (empty file), and included it as a script in the index of my app. This way, the initial HTTP request renews the cookies.

Maybe this can be useful to somebody else

Comment: my understanding is that this issue shouldn't happen when using persistent storage, like redis, but this is exactly my case in production. I can't reproduce it in development